# My Anypoint Studio takes so much time loading for the first time

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Any one can you please help me to know what happens when the anypoint studio starts during the first time ...

After getting loaded, it works fine ...

Also there is a issue i get some time.. Below is the log file pasted...

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change
>   lock for the module: osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.runtime"; type="osgi.bundle";
>   version:Version="3.10.0.v20140318-2214"; singleton:="true" [id=92]
>   STARTED [STARTED]
>
> at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)

Comment: Are you talking about the time it takes to start the Studio itself or Mule inside Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the contents from AnypointStudio\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager